# Mapping problem with Dozer and JAX-WS generated classes

Tags: jax-ws, dozer

I have a set of JAX-WS generated classes which are duplicated in another package. Now I want to map between those classes by using Dozer. The problem I have now is based on JAX-WS not generating setters for Collection types. Instead of calling `set(List<Foo> foo)` I have to call `getFoo().addAll(List<Foo>)`. 
How can I configure Dozer(via XML and API) to respect this?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I figured out how to do it with a static dozer xml configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mappings xmlns="http://dozer.sourceforge.net" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://dozer.sourceforge.net
      http://dozer.sourceforge.net/schema/beanmapping.xsd">
<mapping>
    <class-a>foo.ArrayOfItem
    </class-a>
    <class-b>bar.ArrayOfItem</class-b>
    <field>
        <a>item</a>
        <b set-method="getItem().addAll">item</b>
        <b-hint>bar.Item</b-hint>
    </field>
</mapping>
<mapping>
    <class-a>foo.Item</class-a>
    <class-b>bar.Item</class-b>
</mapping>
```

I was missing the the required `<b-hint>bar.Item</b-hint>`.
Now I only need to do this at runtime via Dozer API...

This fails with `java.lang.ClassCastException: foo.Item cannot be cast to bar.Item` as the hint somehow isn't applied:

```
    BeanMappingBuilder mappingBuilder = new BeanMappingBuilder() {

        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            mapping(
                    "foo.ArrayOfItem",
                    "bar.ArrayOfItem").fields("item", "item",
                    new FieldsMappingOption() {
                        public void apply(
                                FieldMappingBuilder fieldMappingBuilder) {
                            FieldDefinitionBuilder itemFieldDefinitionBuilder = fieldMappingBuilder
                                    .b("item");
                            itemFieldDefinitionBuilder
                                    .theSetMethod("getItem().addAll");
                        }
                    }).hintB(bar.Item.class);
        }
    };
```

---

This is how it works:

```
BeanMappingBuilder mappingBuilder = new BeanMappingBuilder() {

        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            mapping(
                    "foo.ArrayOfItem",
                    "bar.ArrayOfItem").fields("item", "item",
                    new FieldsMappingOption() {
                        public void apply(
                                FieldMappingBuilder fieldMappingBuilder) {
                            FieldDefinitionBuilder itemFieldDefinitionBuilder = fieldMappingBuilder
                                    .b("item");
                            itemFieldDefinitionBuilder
                                    .theSetMethod("getItem().addAll");
                        }
                    }, FieldsMappingOptions.hintB(bar.Item.class));
        }
    };
```

Comment: What version of dozer were you using?  As near as I can tell this doesn't work with the newest one(5.3.2)